# how to map 2 tables from 2 database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a function where it updates my First database. I have created another database for the Frontend work with almost the same table. I want to run a script where it updates the second database table with the new rows every-minute.

I am doing it now using 2 cursors

```
import psycopg2
conn1 = psycopg2.connect(...db1)
conn2 = psycopg2.connect(...db2)
cursor1 = conn1.cursor()
cursor2 = conn2.cursor()
query1 = "SELECT id FROM links"
cursor1.execute(query1)
set1 = set(i[0] for i in cursor1.fetchall())

cursor2.execute(query1)
set2 = set(i[0] for i in cursor2.fetchall())
new_rows_ids = [i for i in set1 if i not in set2]
for i in new_rows_ids:
    # fetch data from cursor1 using the ID
    # insert into links using cursor2
```

This is taking a lot of time to run but gets the job done, is there a faster way I can do this given that the 2 DB are on the same server?

Ideally, I would get rows from db1 where its ID is not in the IDs of db2

Comment: Set up [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) on one of the databases and do an `INSERT` using  the appropriate `LEFT JOIN` to find ids that don't exist in the other database table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver does it matter the "links" in db2 doesn't have all the columns of "links" of db1?

Comment: You can specify the columns in the `INSERT`: `INSERT into links_2(col_1, col_2) SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM links_1`.